# Embed specific Yammer group feed into Sharepoint document library views

Tags: sharepoint, yammer

We have multiple top level folders in our Sharepoint site's document library. Each folder applies to a different team, and team has its own Yammer group.

I want to embed on each folder's page the Yammer feed specific to that group.  So each group can have their own discussion place.  But when I embed the code into the default page, all of the folders' pages get that same group feed.

For example: We have a document library for Pets, with three folders: Cats, Dogs and Fish; and three Yammer groups. When I navigate to the Dogs folder, I want to see the feed for the Dogs group.

I've tried to embed this code on the Dogs folder page:

yam.connect.embedFeed({
container: "#embedded-feed",
network: "ournetwork.org",
feedType: "group",
feedId: "-------"});

But when I do that, I see that feed on all the folders' pages.

I am unable to embed code/web parts directly into the document library's views.

Am I doing something wrong, or can this just not be done?  I don't want to create separate sites for these groups, because the we are always creating new groups around new projects.

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

I've accomplished this task by the following:

Create specific library views for each of the top level folders - start from an existing view but add filter Name = your folder's name.
Create a new page for each folder, add Web Part, choose the document library, then change the Selected View under List Views to the view you just created.
Below that Web Part, Insert another Web Part.  Media and Content > Script Editor, Edit Snippet, insert the code you've extracted from your Yammer group.

Hope this helps someone else!
Matthew